# Simplify Boolean Product of Sums Function

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've got a product of sums expression: ***F=(A'+B+C')&(A+D')(C+D')***

I need to show it as a sum of products and then simplify it. 
Right now I got: ***F=(A'&D')+(A&B&C)+(B&D')+(C&D')***

But the problem is that the values in the truth table are not the same. I believe that I've made some mistakes when trying to show it as a sum of products and simplyfing.

Could you please help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your original expression is a product of sums:

```
(A' + B + C') (A + D') (C + D')
```

If you apply the `and` for the first two sums, you get:

```
(A'A + A'D' + AB + BD') (C + D')
```

`A'A` cancels out to false. In conjunction with the third sum, we get:

```
A'CD' + A'D'D' + ABC + ABD' + BCD' + BD'D'
```

Applying `D'D' = D'` gives us:

```
A'CD' + A'D' + ABC + ABD' + BCD' + BD'
```

`A'CD'` is covered by `A'D'` and can thus be omitted.

The minimized sum of products (the original six terms are covered by just four terms):

```
A'D' + C'D' + BD' + ABC
```

The terms of the expression shown in a [Karnaugh-Veitch map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map):

[image]

The diagram helps to visually grasp which term is covered by which larger term.